# Why is the Geopandas Dataframe returning an Index Error

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm using geopandas 0.6.1 and pandas 1.0.0 in a VS Code notebook. While working today, I was surprised calling the geopandas function head() on a seemingly valid geopandas data frame caused the below error.

Methods such as gpd.columns and gpd.shape work normally and return the expected results. .iloc returns the expected record. For example:

```
for item in new_west_df.columns.values.tolist():
    print(item)

TYPE
NWID
LICENCE
TRADE_NAME
LICENCEE_NAME
CIVIC_ADDRESS
LICENCE_DESCRIPTION
YEAR_OPENED
APPROVED_DATE
SIC
SIC_GROUP
CIVIC_POSTAL_CODE
geometry
```

However, columns() and .geometry cause the below error. In my research of the problem, none of the scenarios were similar to these conditions, and reading the error I can't understand the root cause.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    397                         if cls is not object \
    398                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 399                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    400 
    401             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    687     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    688     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 689     output = repr(obj)
    690     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    691         if idx:

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __repr__(self)
   1370             min_rows=min_rows,
   1371             max_rows=max_rows,
-> 1372             length=show_dimensions,
   1373         )
   1374         result = buf.getvalue()

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in to_string(self, buf, na_rep, float_format, header, index, length, dtype, name, max_rows, min_rows)
   1436             max_rows=max_rows,
   1437         )
-> 1438         result = formatter.to_string()
   1439 
   1440         # catch contract violations

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_string(self)
    359 
    360         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 361         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    362 
    363         if self.truncate_v:

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _get_formatted_values(self)
    346             None,
    347             float_format=self.float_format,
--> 348             na_rep=self.na_rep,
    349         )
    350 

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal, leading_space)
   1172     )
   1173 
-> 1174     return fmt_obj.get_result()
   1175 
   1176 

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in get_result(self)
   1203 
   1204     def get_result(self) -> List[str]:
-> 1205         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1206         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
   1207 

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1483             values = values._values
   1484 
-> 1485         formatter = values._formatter(boxed=True)
   1486 
   1487         if is_categorical_dtype(values.dtype):

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in _formatter(self, boxed)
   1009                 # dummy heuristic based on 10 first geometries that should
   1010                 # work in most cases
-> 1011                 xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = self[~self.isna()][:10].total_bounds
   1012                 if (
   1013                     (-180 <= xmin <= 180)

/Library/Frameworks/anaconda3/envs/vm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in total_bounds(self)
    750         return np.array(
    751             (
--> 752                 b[:, 0].min(),  # minx
    753                 b[:, 1].min(),  # miny
    754                 b[:, 2].max(),  # maxx

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in GeoPandas 0.6.2 (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/releases/tag/v0.6.2), so if you upgrade geopandas, it should be solved.

Comment: One step forward; one step back. I tried to download 0.6.3 via `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` but am getting an ImportError.

Comment: You will need to give more details than that to be able to give any advice (but since it's a new problem, it's probably best to ask a new question)

Comment: beware of discrepancies between conda and conda-forge but this was the root cause and upgrading to 0.6.3 fixed the issue.